# .gitignore: How to ignore file and not ignore folder

Tags: git

I want to ignore files without exclamation marks. I think that the regular expression is  `*[!.]*`, but this ignores folders names too. Does `.gitignore` have a folder/file marker?

Comment: Patterns in `.gitignore` file are not regular expressions, they're *glob* patterns; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `!` is a special character in regexp. So you should use it with `\` if you want to use `!` as just a character.　And your regexp has some other bugs. Your regexp should be `*\!*`

To recognize folders, you can use `/` at the end. And to unignore file/folder, you can use the prefix `!` at the front.

Finally, your .gitignore file should be

```
*\!*
!*\!*/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot "*[!.]*/" is my win conduction

Answer (score 1):

A folder in .gitignore ends with a `/`. I tried to use your expression, but I did not get it to work. But the following entries seem to do the trick:

```
# Ignore Everything
*
# Unignore all files with extensions
!*.*
# Unignore all folders
!*/
```

So when you have these files:

```
a
a.txt
b/a
b/a.txt
```

the files a and b/a get ignored.